# Need a Google Sheets Formula

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I need a formula in Google Sheets that will return a `"Y"` or a `"N"` in column `X` if any of the values in columns `O` through `W` contain a `date` from `2019`.

I have tried `IF(O2:W2)="2019","Y","N"`.

Comment: Welcome. The formula shown is not written using the proper syntax. Please checkout  [Add formulas & functions](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/46977?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(count(iferror(year(DATEVALUE(O2:W2)),)),"Y","N"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(SUM(IF(YEAR(O2:W2)=2019, 1, ))>0, "Y", "N"))
```

[image: 0]